# Migrating a Enterprise Application from Java 6 to Java 8

Tags: swing, java-8, rmi, weblogic-10.x, jaas

**Our Scenario**

1. The entire server code is run on Oracle Web Logic 10.3.6 which is compiled and executed in Java 1.6 environment.
2. The Java Swing Client is compiled in Jdk 1.6
3. Authentication is successful when client is executed in both JRE 1.6 and JRE 1.8
4. Authorization is successful  when client is executed in  JRE 1.6 but fails when client is executed in 
   JRE 1.8
5. In both the client running environement ie JRE 1.6 and 1.8 server returns the expected Subject to the client 
   after authentication
6. However when executing the Swing client in the JRE 1.8 environment on trying to authorize after authentication the Subject is found to be null at the
   Web logic Server Context. 
   ie SubjectUtils.getUserName(weblogic.security.Security.getCurrentSubject()) return null

**Exceptions**
EJBException and SecurityException.
Cannot share stack trace as it is client cod

**Doubts and Confusions**

1. JRE 1.8 Client and weblogic 10.3.6 compatablity issues if any.
2. Any change in Java 8 security as compared to Java 6 security that could be causing any issue.
3. Any Reason why the client run time environment change leading to issues in authorization in JAAS which is at the web logic server
4. Does client environment share any environment related data with the server to which RMI call is made.

[image: Application Architectute Pic]

Comment: don't get me wrong, I've been in your shoes (upgrading from jdk-7 to jdk-8), but this is just *soooo vast*. Upgrade on pre-production and start solving one problem at a time

Comment: The point where I am failing is that I lose the subject in weblogic when my client is wun on JRE 1.8